# there is an error with compilation of graphics.h

Tags: c++, bgi

I downloaded header files and library files for DevC++. After placing the right thing in right place, there is error in compilation with graphics.h.
-Well this is the error I copied

```
" 302   27  C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include\graphics.h   [Note] 'int right' previously declared here"

void printimage(
    const char* title=NULL, 
    double width_inches=7, double border_left_inches=0.75, double border_top_inches=0.75,
    int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    bool active=true, HWND hwnd=NULL
    );
```

Comment: You haven't shown the full error, but what it is telling you is that you have a parameter named `right` and somewhere in the function you're declaring another variable also named `right`.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring an integer with the same name (right) twice, right after each other:

```
int right=0, int right=INT_MAX
```

Comment: And the first `right` should probably be spelled `top`.